# OIDC + Authentik: Which token to give to user for authentication?

Tags: authentication, oauth2, jwt, oidc

I am implementing a web service with a front end and back end. Everything but the login endpoint requires authentication. For authentication I use Authentik. However, I have trouble wrapping my head around which tokens to give to the user, given Authentik's configuration options.

Currently, my authentication process works as follows:

1. On login, the user is sent to the OIDC provider's authorization endpoint and comes back with an `access_code`.
2. Back end sends the `access_code` to the token endpoint to retrieve the `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
3. Back end sends the `id_token` and `refresh_token` to the user and discards the `access_token` (I only need to know if the email address is a company email, which is already included in the `id_token`). The `id_token` and `refresh_token` are stored as cookies (`Secure`, `HttpOnly`, `SameSite=strict`).
4. Whenever the user makes a request to an endpoint requiring authentication, I check the signature on the `id_token`, the intended audience (`aud`) and the expiration time (`exp`). If those checks pass, I trust the email address in the user-supplied `id_token`.
5. If the ID token is expired, I use the `refresh_token` with the token endpoint to get a new `id_token` and `refresh_token`.
6. If the user logs out by themselves, I use the revocation endpoint to revoke both the `refresh_token` and the `id_token`. Afterwards, the cookies are deleted.
7. If the user needs to be logged out by me (left the company), I remove the user's ability to use their company email with Authentik. Then, the next time the `id_token` expires, the refresh will fail and the user will not get a new `id_token`. This means that after one expiration period, the user will be logged out automatically.

I have implemented these steps and the process works quite nicely. I currently do not need to create my own session cookies or sign my own JWTs with a persistent secret, which I would like to keep.

However:
Authentik does not provide a way to configure the `id_token` expiration period. I can only configure that for the `access_code`, `access_token` and `refresh_token`. The lack of documentation on that leads me to believe that I might have misunderstood OIDC.

Could someone enlighten me on this?

EDIT:
As a hacky workaround, I've made my backend reject ID tokens that are older than 5 minutes. This is implemented by checking the `iat` ("issued at") claim. Effectively, my backend now treats ID tokens as having an expiry time of 5 minutes. This perfectly suits my use case. However, I find it confusing that I wasn't able to find a more "proper" solution in OIDC and that I haven't found any guides that highlight this exact problem.

Comment: In #7, why aren't you revoking the ID token and regsitered email? A signed in user even if he left the company will be able to use the unexpired ID token to access the resource.

Comment: @defalt The back end does not have a revocation scheme itself. If it receives a valid ID token, then it treats the user as authenticated. The back end only checks with the OIDC provider when refreshing the ID token. The revocation works by making the ID token short-lived (5-10 minutes) and revoking the refresh token. Then, during the next refresh cycle, the user whose access was revoked will not get another valid ID token.

Comment: But the user still can access the resource for max 10 minutes after being removed from the organization. Is it an acceptable threat for you?

Comment: @defalt Yes, that is acceptable. In fact, that delay is precisely why I was trying to lower the default expiration period of 30 days in the first place. 10 minutes is okay, 30 days is not.

Comment: "Back end sends the id_token and refresh_token to the user and discards the access_token": the user should preferably not have access to the refresh_token and access_token. This is the reason for the Authorization Code Flow. At 2) you can create a session for the user and keep the OIDC tokens in the backend associated with the session ID.

Comment: @ysdx "the user should preferably not have access to the [...] access_token." They don't they only see the *id_token* and refresh token. I do not want to create a session in 2) as that would require the backend to have its own long-running secret and give out its own session tokens, which I believe is redundant with OIDC ID tokens.

Comment: "the user should preferably not have access to the refresh_token" In this case, that is acceptable because Authentik requires the client secret to use the refresh endpoint. The can thus not do anything with the refresh token.

Comment: *"However, I find it confusing that I wasn't able to find a more "proper" solution in OIDC*". The solution is there in OIDC, use access token for authorization to API and ID token for identifying the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need access token to limit authorization and roles of the caller and to identify the caller, you need an ID token. Together they build authorization and authentication. If your web service has administration and/or premium APIs to which only certain users get access, you have to give access token to the user so that your APIs can individually validate roles and permissions at the time of being called by the user. As you are discarding access token, I'm assuming your users have equal authorization to access resources of your web service.

You can still improve your session management by not going off-spec from OIDC and for that you do need access token for the following:

> If the ID token is expired, I use the refresh_token with the token endpoint to get a new id_token and refresh_token.

1. You don't have to refresh the access token just to get a fresh ID token. Instead, use access token and call `/userinfo` endpoint to get the fresh ID token. If the user has been removed from the organization, you won't be able to use that access token to retrieve a new ID token so your web service can immediately clears the session of the user.
2. Access token can be re-verified live by the identity provider (IdP) by using [Token Introspection](https://oauth.net/2/token-introspection/). So, if the user has been removed from the organization, instead of waiting for the token to get expired, your APIs can use token introspection to know that the access token has been revoked before giving access. This will also prevent a small window of attack in which the user has been removed from the org but its cookies still has unexpired access token which can be used to continue using your service.
3. Unlike access token, ID token can neither be introspected nor be forcefully revoked.

> Note: As token introspection request makes I/O with the IdP, it should be periodically used in cases like if the user was inactive for a while or if the cache of token introspection response has expired. If the access token has already expired, there is no need to make token introspection request for that token.

---

> If the user logs out by themselves, I use the revocation endpoint to revoke both the refresh_token and the id_token. Afterwards, the cookies are deleted.

OIDC has [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) for this in which when the user initiates logs out, access and refresh token are revoked at the IdP's end, the web service clears cookies of the user and logs out the user on the web app.

> If the user needs to be logged out by me (left the company), I remove the user's ability to use their company email

OIDC has [Back-Channel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) for this in which the IdP revokes tokens and issues the logout request to your web service and your web service logs out the user.

> Authentik does not provide a way to configure the id_token expiration period. I can only configure that for the access_code, access_token and refresh_token.

Then you should use a short-lived access token and give it to the user.

Comment: "you have to give access token to the user so that your APIs can individually validate roles [...] As you are discarding access token, I'm assuming your users have equal authorization to access resources of your web service."

That is not the case. My users have different permissions based on the group that they are in. Those groups are defined in the OIDC provider and are included in the ID token.

Comment: "You don't have to refresh the access token just to get a fresh ID token. Instead, use access token and call /userinfo endpoint to get the fresh ID token."
That is not the issue. Whether I refresh via `/userinfo` or the refresh token does not really matter to me. What matter to me is that my ID token does not expire fast enough.

Comment: "So, if the user has been removed from the organization, instead of waiting for the token to get expired, your APIs can use token introspection to know that the access token has been revoked before giving access."
That would require talking to the OIDC provider with *every user request*, would it not? I am trying to avoid that as that makes my web app much slower.

Comment: "OIDC has Back-Channel Logout for this in which the IdP revokes tokens and issues the logout request to your web service and your web service logs out the user." Hmm, that doesn't seem very elegant. I currently don't have to keep track of user sessions because the JWT ID token in the client's cookies has everything I need. If I have to track "remotely logged-out" users, then that's pretty much the equivalent of maintaining a revocation list. I'm looking for a more "automatic" solution that doesn't require extra state on the web service.

Comment: "Then you should use a short-lived access token and give it to the user."
Authentik's access token has the same format as the ID token, so I guess that would work. However, won't that give the user to ability to talk to the OIDC provider in my web apps name? More specifically, is the user even supposed to have access to the access token? I thought the access token was intended for communication between my web service and the OIDC provider / resource provider.

Comment: Which claim of the ID token are you using to identify groups and how your access and ID token are same? This is way off from OIDC specification and is almost a custom JWT. As written in the answer, you can cache token introspection response and only use it periodically. Back-Channel logout isn't just about force log out of the user. That's only the final step. Its first step is to revoke tokens.

Comment: "Which claim of the ID token are you using to identify groups [...]?" The "groups" claim. It's an array of strings. Not sure if that is OIDC spec or a custom claim from Authentik.

Comment: "[...] how your access and ID token are same?" In Authentik, the access token is also a JWT that has almost exactly the same format as the ID token. From what I understand, the access token format is not specified in OIDC spec. Instead, the client should treat it as opaque. That is one of the reasons why I am hesitant to give it to the user and use it to identify the user. Additionally, I don't think I'm even *supposed* to give the access token to the user, given that is allows API requests with the authority of the client.

Comment: The user can have access token if the web app is using it to call the APIs of your web service. For what purpose your web service uses access token?

Comment: My web service is not using the access token at all. I'm only talking to the OIDC provider to get the ID token. I don't need to make any other API calls except for token refreshing, which doesn't require the access token (and instead requires the refresh token and client secret). It doesn't make sense to me that I should give the user an access token that would allow the user to speak to Authentik directly.

Comment: The user cannot talk to Authentik just by possessing access token. It requires client ID and client secret which only your web service has.